# AES/RSA encryption/decryption in ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, aes, rsa

I am working on a project in which I want to keep the encryption and decryption algorithm along with the NDK itself to make it secure or unable to reverse engineer it and also it will be a lot faster than in Java.

I have tried several c codes wrapping up in NDK but not get success in it.

Please let me know how can I do it. Any code reference will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can compile OpenSSL for android. https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

Comment: Note that modern Android already does the expensive crypto operations using native code from OpenSSL, so you're effort likely won't speed anything up.

Comment: @Endre Borcsok
I have managed to setup OpenSSL but now I am not able to do the encryption as I don't know C. I have google a lot always get some issues.
Any reference so that I can easily call a native method in java and get the encrypted text returned.

Comment: @James I want to keep the aes encryption/decryption methods with my keys in the ndk so that no one can reverse engineer it.

Comment: _"so that no one can reverse engineer it."_ Using native code is not going to prevent people from reverse-engineer it or finding secrets.